# i want to restrict user to just enter integers should give error in C#and if user enters any alphabet or string characters it

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i want to restrict user to just enter integers and if user enters any alphabet or string characters it should display error in c#

```
Console.WriteLine("enter a");
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("enter b");
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Program e = new Program();

int sum= e.sum( a, b);
Console.WriteLine("sum is " + sum);


public int sum(int a, int b)
{

   int sum = a + b;
   return sum;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please improve the formatting of you're code snippet and be more precise about your requirements (it currently _does_ show an error because `int.Parse` throws an exception if there are non-digit characters). And you are probably looking for [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hello thanks for replying but int.parse doesn't show error and there is nothing wrong with the code. i wanted to add the restriction in above code so that if the user enter any string type characters then it displays error and i want a code snippet for that.

Answer (score 1):

#### use this only if you want to check condition for integer

```
string strValue = Convet.toString("YourValue");
if(int.TryParse(strValue , out value))
{
}
else
{
  //Value is Not Integer.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check before you parse the input to int.

```
string input = Console.Readline();
if(IsInt(input))
    int a = int.Parse(input);
else
    //Error message here

private bool IsInt(string in)
{
    string intChars = "0123456789";
    return in.All(intChars.Contains);
}
```

Another option would be to use int.TryParse(), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx on that.

Comment: You're `IsInt()` method returns false for "32", I don't think this is what OP wanted.

Comment: So simply change it to `return in.All(intChars.Contains);`

Answer (score 0):

```
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        string b = Console.ReadLine();
        int inputnumber1 = 0;
        int inputnumber2= 0;
        if (int.TryParse(a,out inputnumber1))
        {

        }
```

like that

Answer (score 0):

you can do a try catch:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter a");
    string a = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("enter b");
    string b = Console.ReadLine();

    a=int.parse(a);
    b=int.parse(b);



    Program e = new Program();

    int sum= e.sum( a, b);
    Console.WriteLine("sum is " + sum);


    public int sum(int a, int b)
    {

       int sum = a + b;
       return sum;

    }
}
catch(FormatException e){Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");}
```

or you can also do  something like this to get the user input and repeat the ask to get the parameters if it fails:

```
Boolean wrongInput=true;
string read;
int a;int b;
while(wrongInput)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("enter a");
    read = Console.ReadLine(); 
    bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(read, out a);
    if(isNumeric){wrongInput=false;}
  }
wronginput=while(wrongInput)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("enter b");
    read = Console.ReadLine();
    bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(read, out b);
    if(isNumeric){wrongInput=false;}
  }
```